# Lacking possible lambda-optimization

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me if there's a deeper reason for the following code ...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    auto f = [&]() -> int
    {
        return i + j + k;
    };
    cout << sizeof f << endl;
}
```

... that the optimizer places three pointers (12 / 24 bytes, depending if 32 or 64 bit) inside the lambda-object and not just **one** pointer to the stack-frame ?

Comment: Because the code, as written, has 3 references.  Some compiler's optimizers may be savvy enough to replace those references with a stack-frame pointer.  If no/few compilers provide such an optimization, it may either be very hard, or not sufficiently an optimization "win".

Comment: Of course this would be a significant win because you've not to load three pointers and save registers.

Comment: By "not sufficiently an optimization win" I meant that the frequency that such an optimization could be employed may be so infrequent that it isn't worth the effort to implement.  (Maybe it could be employed very frequently.  I don't know.  I'm just speculating.)

Comment: Of course lambdas with more once capture-refernce are very often. Maybe that's just no none has thought about this optimization yet.

Comment: If you want, you could implement the optimization for GCC or Clang and submit it.

Comment: It would be easier to suggest this optimization to the folks involved in the implementation.

Comment: Both are open source software, and the folks involved in the implementation are self-nominated because of their interest in the technology as contributors to the projects.  This kind of optimization sounds just like the kind of thing someone could volunteer to contribute to one (or both) of the projects.

Comment: The compiler could make this lambda have a size of 1 under the standard.  Why stop at a pointer?  (under as if, the uncalled lambda's body can be eliminated).

Comment: Because if you have multiple references into the parent stack-frame you'd need at least _one_ pointer. A lambda might be inlined, but it also might be an independent function; and in the latter case this kind of function is just like a method with a this-pointer (I know that lambdas don't have a this to the lambda-object).